# append element that created with createElement() to elements that have specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and I want to append the "ul" variable to elements that have the "myselectItems" class.

my problem is here

```
selectedElement[i].appendChild(ul);
```

html code

```
<div class="myselectItems"></div>
```

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
let items = [
   'fab fa-500px',
   'fab fa-accessible-icon',
   'fab fa-accusoft',
   'fas fa-address-book',
],
ul = document.createElement('select');
ul.setAttribute("id", "myselect");
ul.setAttribute("name", "myselect");
ul.setAttribute("class", "myselect");
items.forEach(item => {
  let li = document.createElement('option');
   ul.appendChild(li);
      li.innerHTML += item;
 });
 const selectedElement = document.querySelectorAll('.myselectItems');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedElement.length; i++) {
       selectedElement[i].appendChild(ul);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're appending the same `select` element each time, so that single instance gets moved between elements.

To fix this you can use `cloneNode()` before you append in order to create a new `select` instance for each `div`.

```
selectedElement[i].appendChild(ul.cloneNode(true));
```

Also note that you should remove the `id` attribute you set on the `select`, otherwise it will be duplicated which is invalid. `id` must be unique.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let items = [
    'fab fa-500px',
    'fab fa-accessible-icon',
    'fab fa-accusoft',
    'fas fa-address-book',
  ];
  var ul = document.createElement('select');
  ul.setAttribute("name", "myselect");
  ul.setAttribute("class", "myselect");
  items.forEach(item => {
    let li = document.createElement('option');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML += item;
  });
  const selectedElement = document.querySelectorAll('.myselectItems');
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedElement.length; i++) {
    selectedElement[i].appendChild(ul.cloneNode(true));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myselectItems"></div>
<div class="myselectItems"></div>
<div class="myselectItems"></div>
```

Also note that you can simplify the code:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let items = ['fab fa-500px', 'fab fa-accessible-icon', 'fab fa-accusoft', 'fas fa-address-book'];
  let selectHtml = `<select name="myselect" class="myselect">${items.map(t => `<option>${t}</option>`)}</select>`;

  $('.myselectItems').append(selectHtml); // jQuery version

  //document.querySelectorAll('.myselectItems').forEach(el => el.innerHTML = selectHtml); // plain JS version  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myselectItems"></div>
<div class="myselectItems"></div>
<div class="myselectItems"></div>
```